# ADO RecordSet Issue - Missing Data

Tags: asp-classic

I am having an very weird issue.  Recently, one of my customers moved their website (classic asp) to a new server (2008/IIS7/MSSQL 2005) and now I am getting recordsets where fields have no data.  When I profile the SQL Query, I see the query running, and when I rerun it in SSMS it returns data for all the fields.  For example the sql query returns:

```
Col1          Col2
John Smith    Blue
Jane Doe      Red
```

but when I loop through the dataset I get

```
Col1          Col2
John Smith    
Jane Doe
```

No idea how this is happening and I am wondering if anyone else has run into an issue like it?  Here is the code:

```
dim db
Set db = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
DSN = "dsn=provider=sqloledb;Data Source=.;User Id=;Password=;Initial Catalog="
db.Open DSN

Set rs = db.Execute(query)

do while not rs.EOF
    'do stuff...

    rs.movenext
loop

rs.Close
db.Close
set rs = nothing
set db = nothing
```

Thanks for the help.

Wade

Comment: @Wade73 Please post the query which is executed. I always write the query to the page ( between <h1> tags to make it stand out ) just to be sure that the query is exact as I would expect ( f.i. no quotes or double quotes where they shouldn't be.

Comment: I can already capture the query in SQL Profiler, so I know it works (I also captured it on the page - same query).  It is a simple select statement, so I am not sure what it might add to the question.

Comment: @Wade73 Do you try the RecordSet.Open variant ? `rs.Source = query` and `rs.Open` ? I always assumed the .Execute was for insert/update/delete queries ( but of course you always keep on using the code that works - for me : open for recordsets, and execute for insert/update/delete. Try, just to see what happens.

Comment: @Wade73 Are you sure that you made no typo in your 'do stuf...' part ? If resume on error is active, you might not notice it. And is `option explicit' on ? This would use any var you use, but return empty strings. It all depends a bit on what you do with the stuff.

Comment: There's not enough information provided to resolve the problem

Comment: @Dee I am not sure what else I could add that would help?

Comment: @Edelcom I use this method all the time, but seeing this is such a bizarre problem it might be the way to do it.  I am not using on error resume next, so I don't believe the problem is in the do stuff portion.

Comment: @Wade73 And the `option explicit` ? Is this active ?

Comment: @Edelcom, option explicit is not set (I didn't write the original code), but I am using dim in this case to create the variables.

Comment: @Wade73 Ok, but that doesn't mean a thing. If you use dim Data1 and use Data1 to fill the data but you use Datal in the loop to write it to the web page, you are in trouble. Sorry to keep on saying the same thing, but too much times you are looking for something 'strange' only to find out it's something really obvious ( at least I have had such cases ). Depending on the font used in your editor a 1 and lower case l can look very much the same ( just to name something obvious here ).

Comment: your loop code is not rendering the correct output but we have no idea what the loop code looks like so there is little chance of aqnyone helping you.  two things are possible sources of error.  the query is incorrect and values are not available to the loop or the loop code is not handling the values correctly.  you already stated the query has been double checked and is working so that leaves the loop code.

Comment: I do a response.write rs("fieldname")

Comment: then try a completely separate debugging page and query for the missing data and see if you can output the value.   what you are giving us looks valid "response.write rs("fieldname")" so we can't tell what is wrong.  it could even be an html-css problem as mentioned earlier where the data is returned but not being displayed correctly - try a view source on the page and search it to see if the values are simply missplaced.  you are in a debugging stage now and we can only offer general suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was a field that was nvarchar(max), when I changed it to nvarchar(2000) the data showed up.  Apparently, not able to find anything to back this up, there was a issue with classic asp and these fields.  The workaround, if you need the nvarchar(max), is to place it last in the select statement.

HTH

Wade

Update: Apparently, this is also an issue with text and ntext.  Thanks to [Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65775/keith) for mentioning this.

Comment: Same problem exists with text/ntext columns.

Answer (score 3):

When you have `Memo` field or `nvarchar(max)` in your case the value in the recordset is being reset after the first time you read it. Why? Microsoft.

So, such code will fail to show the value in the second Response.Write line:

```
do while not rs.EOF
    Response.Write(rs("memofield"))
    Response.Write(rs("memofield"))
    rs.movenext
loop
```

Solution is store the value in local variable then use this variable:

```
Dim strCurValue
do while not rs.EOF
   strCurValue = rs("memofield")
   Response.Write(strCurValue)
   Response.Write(strCurValue)
   rs.movenext
loop
```

Comment: I tried setting it to a local variable, but that didn't seem to work.  Changing the datatype to varchar(200) worked though.

Comment: @Wade that's weird.. maybe updating the OLEDB drivers and using Native client instead of the ordinary `provider=sqloledb` will solve this issue without having to change the field.

Comment: With Server 2008 I would assume the ADO library is the latest, but you may be right about the provider.

Comment: @Wade indeed, the provider is defined by the connection string in the code.